# What type of normalization uses Orange3 On Distance Pearson Correlation Widget

Tags: correlation, orange

I'm trying to compute Pearson Correlation on several columns using Orange3 distance widget but results are completely different of what i get in R.

The R command i am running is

```
head(DF_COMBRETURNS,30)

       returns1    returns2    returns3
1   0.051533110  0.08991458  0.05758710
2   0.025753284  0.10480611  0.07194245
3  -0.057929969  0.18695782  0.01437815
4  -0.070844336  0.09703665  0.02875216
5  -0.038669760 -0.01491424  0.01437195
6   0.000000000 -0.09695704 -0.01436988
7   0.045132173 -0.04479283  0.00000000
8   0.012889089  0.02987527 -0.02874389
9  -0.012887428 -0.05226611  0.02875216
10  0.000000000  0.08964590  0.04311584
11 -0.032222723  0.14927601  0.02873150
12 -0.038679732  0.02981070  0.02872325
13  0.000000000  0.09685591  0.05743001
14  0.012898233 -0.06698921 -0.07174631
15  0.000000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
16 -0.006448285  0.07448235  0.05743825
17 -0.038692204  0.02232807  0.00000000
18 -0.038707180 -0.04464618 -0.04305396
19 -0.064536947 -0.12655401 -0.12921752
20 -0.012915725 -0.01490757  0.02875216
21  0.025834787  0.02981959  0.04311584
22 -0.025828114  0.02981070  0.08619451
23 -0.012917393  0.00000000  0.04306014
24  0.019378593 -0.06705409  0.00000000
25  0.000000000 -0.02236636  0.02869440
26  0.012916559  0.01491424  0.02868617
27  0.012914891  0.15657620  0.12905076
28  0.000000000  0.02977741  0.01432049
29 -0.012913223 -0.05209496  0.01431844
30  0.000000000 -0.03723008 -0.04294918

cor(DF_COMBRETURNS[,c(5,8,11)])

           returns1    returns2  returns3
returns1  1.00000000 -0.03619446 0.2682558
returns2 -0.03619446  1.00000000 0.6724748
returns3  0.26825585  0.67247477 1.0000000
```

But when trying to compute the same data in Orange3 distance widget gives me a completly different result. When reading the documentation about the widget seems Orange normalized the data always but i don't know if this is the reason of the diference. What i am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pearson Correlation Distance is defined as (1 - cor) / 2

Use

```
(1 - cor(DF_COMBRETURNS[,c(5,8,11)])) / 2
```

to compare the results

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it posible to compute perason correlation (no distances) in orange3?

Comment: Got it. There is a correlation widget, i hadn't seen it sorry. Thanks again.